# LSTM pytorch not learning

Tags: pytorch, lstm, loss-function

I am learning LSTM and language models, I developed the following code for a character level text generation:

Here is the model class:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, embedding_dim, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
                 # Layers:
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(input_size, embedding_dim, padding_idx=0)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)  # regularization to reduces overfitting and to increase stability
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.o = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        
    def forward(self, x, hidden, cell):
        out = self.embed(x)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(out.unsqueeze(1), (hidden, cell))
        out = self.fc(out.reshape(out.shape[0], -1))
        out = self.o(out)
        return out, (hidden, cell)
    
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        cell = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        return hidden, cell


n_chars, embedding_dim, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size = 55, 20, 256, 2, 55
model = RNN(n_chars, embedding_dim,  hidden_size, num_layers, n_chars).to(device)
```

And this is the train function, where I have the problem:

```
def train(model, optimizer, criterion, epochs=10, every=5):   
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        k = random.randint(0,len(data))
        x, y = get_batch(k)
        xt, yt = tensorize(x,y)
        mean_loss = 0
        L = len(xt)

        for i in range(L):
            hidden, cell = model.init_hidden(batch_size)  # not doing this will cause an error
            out, (hidden, cell) = model(xt[i].unsqueeze(0), hidden, cell)
            target = yt[i].unsqueeze(0)

            loss = criterion(out, target)

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            mean_loss += loss.item()

        if epoch % every == 0:
            print("epoch = ", epoch ," mean loss = ", mean_loss/L)
```

However, the loss seems to not change at all. What did I do wrong, please?
Note: I am giving the model character by character and not the entire batch at once.

Comment: Just guessing here, but I think you forgot `optimizer.zero_grad()` somewhere in the code.

Comment: No, I added it, but still the same problem, the loss keeps at the same range of values (3.7-4.1). Like if the model is reset at every epoch.